# Get method name on event

Tags: backbone.js

I have a simple model that intercepts error. How can I get name of method that has created an error?

```
export class CommonModel extends Backbone.Model {
  constructor(options) {
    super(options);
    this.on("error", this.onError);
  }

  onError(model, response, options) {
    let method = ???
    console.log(method); // GET or POST or PUT or DELETE
  }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like valid syntax, what is that? typescript?

Comment: Are you kidding? It's ES6

Comment: hahah really? oops. i havent been keeping up on the latest :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work, it looks like xhr does not have any information about the request, only data about the response. Heres the code:

```
// i grabbed this from here: https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1438
Backbone.ajax = function() {
  var xhr = Backbone.$.ajax.apply(Backbone.$, arguments);
  xhr.method = arguments[0].type; // <<------- this part is the most important
  return xhr;
};

var BaseModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function(options) {
    this.on('error', this.onError)
  },
  onError: function(model, xhr, options) {
    alert(xhr.method)
  }
});

var SomeModel = BaseModel.extend({url: '/someresource/'});

// HERE ARE THE TESTS - when you run it you will see 4 alerts (in no particular order since `alert()` is blocking)
try {
    (new SomeModel()).fetch()
} catch(e) {}
try {
    (new SomeModel()).save()
} catch(e) {}
try {
  (new SomeModel({id: 123})).save()
} catch(e) {}
try {
    (new SomeModel({id: 123})).destroy()
} catch(e) {}
```

Test it yourself here: http://jsfiddle.net/ghcp2g2t/